# How to get the count of only special character in a string using Regex?

Tags: c#

If my input string is `~!@#$%^&*()_+{}:"<>?`

How do I get the count of each special character using Regex? For example:

```
Regex.Matches(inputText, "each special character").Count;
```

Comment: Any particular reason you want to use a regex for this? What counts as a "special" character in your view?

Comment: This is the approach that i need to follow. All the characters available in our keyboard except alphabets and numbers .

Comment: @user1618587 do you mean non A-Z and non 0-9? what about other languages?

Comment: @user1618587: How are we supposed to know what characters are on *your* keyboard? Does your keyboard have a £ key? Does it have a ¥? Or €? You better approach would be to count the number of *allowed* characters and subtract it from the count of *all* characters.

Answer (score 4):

This should be the answer to your question:

```
Regex.Matches("Little?~ birds! like to@ sing##", "[~!@#$%^&*()_+{}:\"<>?]").Count
```

Count should return 6 matches, change the sentence to other variable or something else.

You can find more info about regex expressions here:
http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm

Best Regards!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of thinking of every special characters and adding them up, do it the other way; count every letters/digits and subtract them from the count.

You can do that with a simple one-liner :

```
string input = "abc?&;3";
int numberOfSpecialCharacters = input.Length - input.Count(char.IsLetterOrDigit); //Gives 3
```

Which you can also change to

```
int numberOfSpecialCharacters = input.Count(c => !char.IsLetterOrDigit(c));
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not the best way to do this. here is the `Linq` based solution

```
string chars = "~!@#$%^&*()_+{}:\"<>?";
foreach (var item in chars.Where(x=> !char.IsLetterOrDigit(x)).GroupBy(x => x))
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1}",item.Key,item.Count()));
}
```

I understand that you need to count each spl character count. Correct me If am mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to follow other approach then you can use.

```
string str =  "@123:*&^789'!@#$*()_+=";
            int count = 0;
            foreach (char c in str)
            {
                if (!char.IsLetterOrDigit(c.ToString(),0))
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show(count.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

The non-regex way (which sounds much easier) it to make a list of characters you want to check  and use Linq to find the count of those characters.

```
string inputString = "asdf1!%jkl(!*";

List<char> charsToCheckFor = new List<char>() { '!', '@', '#', ..... };

int charCount = inputString.Count(x => charsToCheckFor.Contains(x));
```

I am making you write in all the characters you need to check for, because you need to figure out what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while and I needed a similar answer for handling password validation. Pretty much what VITA said, but here was my specific take for others needing it for the same thing:

```
var pwdSpecialCharacterCount = Regex.Matches(item, "[~!@#$%^&*()_+{}:\"<>?]").Count;
var pwdMinNumericalCharacters = Regex.Matches(item, "[0-9]").Count;
var pwdMinUpperCaseCharacters = Regex.Matches(item, "[A-Z]").Count;
var pwdMinLowerCaseCharacters = Regex.Matches(item, "[a-z]").Count;
```